# ImageControl dont show in execution

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

I use this code in XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="img2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Width="128" Height="128" Canvas.Left="343" 
       Canvas.Top="192" 
       Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Trophy-Gold-icon11.png"/>
```

I use visual studio 2012. Before running, image control shows assigned image (in designer window) but at execution time, the image is not displayed by image control.

Comment: Make sure image `build action` is set to `Resource`.

Comment: How change **build action** to **Resource** ?

Comment: Select your image in Solution Explorer, switch to the Properties window, and change Build Action to Resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure image `build action` is set to `Resource`. (right click on an image and then go to properties, set build action to resource)

Also, instead of `siteoforigin` use `application` authority -

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Trophy-Gold-icon11.png"
```